# How to create break line in sql

Tags: sql, hiveql, line-breaks

I supposed to create  2 sentence in a remark column and it should be displayed in 2 lines specifically in hiveql.

Currently I'm just using pipeline to concatenate the two sources

select **'Remark 1:' || table.column1 || 'Remark 2:' || table.column2** from table;

**My output:**

```
Remark column 
Remark 1: <table.column1> Remark 2: <table.column2>
```

**My expected:**

```
Remark column 
Remark 1: <table.column1>
Remark 2: <table.column2>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way is to use a char(13) to break the line
So you can concatenate or juste replace a key caracter with it. (Like putting a "," where you want to break.

```
--CHAR(13) = Break
--CHAR(10) = newline
--CHAR(9) = Tab
---------SAMPLES
REPLACE(@strInput, ',', CHAR(13));
REPLACE(@strInput, ',', CHAR(10) + CHAR(13));
REPLACE(@strInput, ',', CHAR(9));
```